# git authentication error in capistrano 3.2.1

Tags: git, amazon-ec2, capistrano3, ruby-on-rails-4.1, ruby-2.1

i have added the server_users rsa.pub key to git,the error i'm getting is as

```
Running /usr/bin/env git ls-remote -h http://git.example.com/nishant/pro-gasket.git on 52.24.70.121
DEBUG[c40f8fa6] Command: ( GIT_ASKPASS=/bin/echo GIT_SSH=/tmp/pro-gasket/git-ssh.sh /usr/bin/env git ls-remote -h http://git.example.com/nishant/pro-gasket.git )
DEBUG[c40f8fa6]     fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://git.example.com/nishant/pro-gasket.git/'
DEBUG[c40f8fa6]     
DEBUG[c40f8fa6] Finished in 1.549 seconds with exit status 128 (failed).
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host 52.24.70.121: exit
/home/codebajra/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@pro-gasket/gems/capistrano-3.2.1/lib/capistrano/tasks/git.rake:28:in `exit'
```

git version in server is 1.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since server uses ssh to connect to github, so use the repourl for ssh one.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the basics of -

- ensuring that git is installed on the remote host, and
- ensuring that the failing user has rights to the repository

You might be encountering a scenario where either you deployments have just stopped working, or that they are working for some users and not for others - i.e. you know the remote host is setup correctly.

In this case the failing user may not have their SSH key added to the ssh agent locally - this is required because Capistrano uses SSH agent forwarding (i.e. forwards your local ssh key to your remote host).

To fix, ensure your agent is running (locally) as follows:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
```

and then add your key

```
ssh-add
```

Verify that your identity has been added as follows:

```
ssh-add -l
```